# Characteristic of $W(K)_L$ is $0$ when $L$ is p adic field and $K$ is finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $L$ be finite extension of $\Bbb{Q}_p$ and $K$ be a finite field.
$W(K)_L$ be ramified witt ring of $K$.

> I want to prove $W(K)_L$ has characteristic $0$.

Here, we admit $W(K)_L$ is integral domain.

Suppose $l$ is prime except for $p$, then $l(1,0,0,・・・)＝(l,・・・)$ is unit in $W(K)_L$, so it's never zero.

The last thing I should check is $p(1,0,0,・・・)$ is never zero.

Let $L/\Bbb{Q}_p$ be extension of ramified index $e$.

Then, $p(1,0,0,・・・)＝π^eu(1,0,0,・・・)＝u(0,0,・・・,0,1,0,・・・)$ ($u$ is invertible element of ring of integers of $L$).

Why **u(0,0,・・・,0,1,0,・・・) is nonzero**?

Referrence:
This kind of argument and definition of ramified Witt vector is in Peter Schneider's 'Galois representation and (φ,Γ)modules'.

Comment: If I understand the notation well, the element $u(0,\dots,0,1,0,\dots)=(0,\dots,0,\bar u,\dots)$, where $\bar u$ is the reduction of $u$ to the residue field of $L$. As $u$ is invertible, $\bar u$ is non-zero, hence the $(0,\dots,0,\bar u,\dots)$ is not zero as well.

Comment: I think element of each entry is the element of the same ring, K, so reduction does not make sense ..?

Comment: I think I might be missing something with your question, but aren't we only supposed to show that $\left(0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots\right)\neq0$ because $u$ is a unit? Then it's obviously true because as a set, $W\left(K\right)_{L}$ is just $K^{\mathbb{N}}$.